# Vodafone Ubuntu Webbook: Keyboard and mouse-pad not working

Tags: drivers

The keyboard and trackpad of my [Vodafone Ubuntu Webbook](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/the-ubuntu-vodafone-webbook-disappoints-reviewers) are not responding, only the power button works. I want to know if this is a software or hardware problem, if it's the former how can I get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect external some another keyboard and mouse, which was not connected before. Tit will be detected as a new device and will be set enabled by default.  If this works, you have a hardware problem, or your devices inside of the notebook a re disabled in the config.